# Shell - putting strings in a vector has a strange behavior with spaces

Tags: shell

I have to ask you this because its driving me crazy since too many days.

I will explain my problem with an example:

```
s1="aa a"
s2="bbb"
s3="ccc"
s4="ddd"

v=($s1 $s2 $s3 $s4)
echo ${v[0]}
echo ${v[1]}
echo ${v[2]}
echo ${v[3]}
echo ${v[4]}
```

The output is:

```
aa
a
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

My problem is that `v[0]` contains `"aa"` and `v[1]` contains `"a"`. I don't get why `v[0]` is not `"aa a"`.

My output should be:

```
aa a
bbb
ccc 
ddd
```

...and `v[4]` should be empty

Why does the space create this problem?

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: For reference, this answer explains when to use quotes around a shell variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067297/5411198

Comment: Note once you declare the array `v=("$s1" "$s2" "$s3" "$s4")`  you can print its values as: `for ((i=0; i<${#v[@]}; i++)); do echo ${v[i]}; done` (bash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **add double quotes around your variables**, like this:

```
v=("$s1" "$s2" "$s3" "$s4")
```

...so that you get:

```
v=("aa a" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd")
```

**It is generally always a good idea to put your variables inside double quotes.**

---

Without quotes you get the following:

```
v=(aa a bbb ccc ddd)
```

...so `aa` & `a` are interpreted as 2 separate strings.